# Fetching data from firebase based on foreign key

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase realtime DB and I would like to fetch data based on categoryId.

Here's the Db structure.

[image]

Here's the code:

```
  Future<void> fetchAndSetProducts(String id) async { 
const url = 'https://random-9006.firebaseio.com/products.json';
try {
  final response = await http.get(url);
  final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  print(extractedData.toString()); 
}
```

How to construct the URL in order to get the products per the categoryId passed?

Comment: why are you not using the firebase plugins?

Comment: Just learning @PeterHaddad

Comment: I understand, but it would be easier for you fetching and manipulating data in firebase, if you use the following plugins https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following plugin to fetch data from firebase:

Inside `pubspec.yaml`:

```
dependencies:
  firebase_database: ^4.1.1
  firebase_core: ^0.5.0+1
```

in `main()` function initialize Firebase:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Then you can get the data using the following way:

```
Future<DataSnapshot> getData(String category){
 var dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("products");
 return await dbRef.orderByChild("categoryId").equalTo(category).once();
}
```

You can then call this `future` method inside a `FutureBuilder`. For `FutureBuilder` check:

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data#5-display-the-data

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Comment: appreciate the detailed explanation. Can you also tell me how to fetch via the URL?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

You make the URL data type `final` and the URL becomes:

```
 final url = 'https://mydburl.firebaseio.com/products.json?orderBy="categoryId"&equalTo="$id"';
```